# Converting functions into a methods of a class in python

Tags: python, class, function, methods

I'm trying to get the hang of python 2.6, which is my introduction to a programming language. I'm following Learn Python the Hard Way and I must have missed something. I have a set of functions that I want to combine into a class. These functions are contained [here](http://pastebin.com/QDbVRALq). I tried to combine these into a class called "Parsers". This code is contained [here](http://pastebin.com/0tqbktKb).

The functions themselves work outside of the class. I'm trying to call the functions out of the class like this:

import the module:

```
>>> from ex48 import parser2
```

Assign the class:

```
>>> parser_class = parser2.Parsers()
```

Call a function:

```
>>> parser_class.parse_subject(word_list, ('noun', 'player'))
```

I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ex48/parser2.py", line 60, in parse_subject
    verb = parse_verb(word_list)
NameError: global name 'parse_verb' is not defined
```

Not sure why it's telling me that. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Terminology quibble: a "method" is by definition a "callable member of a class". Your question does not involve "converting methods into a class", it's placing functions in a class or converting functions to methods (as you correctly say in the body of your question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused as to what your code is doing.

This does not assign, a class, it creates an instance, and assigns that instance to a variable:

```
parser_class = parser2.Parsers()
```

This calls a method on that instance:

```
parser_class.parse_subject(word_list, ('noun', 'player'))
```

The following tells you that there is no global function (or indeed variable of any type) `parse_verb`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ex48/parser2.py", line 60, in parse_subject
    verb = parse_verb(word_list)
NameError: global name 'parse_verb' is not defined
```

I expect that you want to change that to `verb = self.parse_verb(word_list)`, which will call the `parse_verb` method of the same object (`self`).

Comment: This seems like the right answer, but he needs to change _all_ of his method calls to explicit calls on `self`, not just this one. (For example, the very next line calls `parse_object`. But I think this is clear enough to explain why he needs to add `self.` to `parse_verb`, in which case he'll figure that out.

Comment: Why can't you see it? He provided a link to the code, where the line you fixed is line 24.

Comment: @user1367173 (1) you should accept an answer. Choose whichever one helped you the most; (2) What you see in angle brackets is a textual representation of the return value of the expression you just evaluated.

Comment: I just deleted a response to this that was a question. I was able to call the method of the class, but I couldn't figure out how to get to its values. I did a little playing around and figured it out. `code`>>> word_list = lexicon3.scan("kill the bear")
>>> sentence = parser_class.parse_sentence(word_list)
>>> sentence.subject
'player'
>>> sentence.verb
'kill'
>>> sentence.object
'bear'
>>>

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here, one mechanical, one conceptual. I'll deal with the latter first.

The whole point of a class is that its instances represent some kind of object in your model of the world. For example, a "sentence" is an object, so it makes sense to have a class called `Sentence`, but a "parsers" is not an object, so `Parsers` is probably going to be a confused class. Looking at things less abstractly, a class usually has some kind of state, encapsulated in data members that its methods work on.

What you really have here is a parser function that returns a `Sentence` object (or raises a `ParserError`). This function could be a method of `Sentence`, or it could be a free function; it could also be a method of a `Parser` class if there were any reason for such an object to exist in your model, but there doesn't seem to be one.

If you're just looking to encapsulate all those helper functions so they don't litter the global namespace (a good idea in itself), you don't need to abuse a class to do that. Just make them local functions inside `parse_sentence`, or put them in a module called `parsers`.

Now, on to the mechanical problem: If you have a method in a class, you normally only call it through dot syntax: `someObject.methodName(params)`. When a method calls another method of the same object, you use the special `self` parameter (which you've correctly listed as the first param of each method) to do that. So:

```
verb = self.parse_verb(word_list)
obj = self.parse_object(word_list)
```

… and so on for all the other method calls in your sample.

Not every language requires an explicit `self` like this. For example, in C++ or related languages (Java, C#, etc.), a method can call another method without specifying a target, and it's implicitly assumed that the target is `this` (the C++ equivalent of `self`).

Comment: This is very informative, and I agree with your conceptual argument. I'm just following the tutorial, and I think part of the intention of that tutorial was to get me to the realization that classes aren't intended for a use case such as this. Thank you for taking the time to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are working from a python interactive session.

If you've made any changes to `parser2.py` after importing `parser2`, then you have to

```
reload(parser2)
```

to make those changes known to the interactive interpreter.